# .htaccess Subfolder Redirect from http:// to www

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to push my subfolder from using http://example.com/chat to www.example.com/chat. I've tried the following in my subfolder's .htaccess file with no luck. It does not push the page to a www.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subfolder(?:/.*)?)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in `/subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

i.e. keep redirect rule before internal routing one and simplify your regex.